# Can we use Spring Cloud Actuator /refresh over TCP Telnet Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, amazon-kinesis, spring-actuator

I currently have multiple Spring Boot applications built on Java.

Some services listen on TCP Telnet
and some are HTTP Services with RESTful APIs.

I am trying to implement the spring actuator /refresh using spring cloud bus with a kinesis binder. Is it possible to go with this approach for services listening on TCP telnet? If yes, how?

For implementing spring cloud with kinesis, I have added these dependencies in my pom.xml

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-kinesis</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.344</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-bus</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: yes, bus has a `RefreshRemoteApplicationEvent` that you can emit

Comment: @spencergibb Please elaborate on this

Comment: @spencergibb Please elaborate